# Looking for panel dataset

Tags: data-request

Hi I am looking for panel data set for my academic project. It should not be too small . Any links to panel data sets with good business value will be helpful.

Comment: [Panel data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data)

Comment: Sorry, this question is very unclear. If find it hard to believe that *any* panel data (which philshem had to link to because you did not) will satisfy your needs. Please [edit] your question, give specific requirements (*good business value* says nothing) related to your *academic project*. And what *machine*?

Comment: Link to any open source panel data would be appreciated. I meant to type it should not be too big to work in my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

[gretl - Gnu Regression, Econometrics and Time-Series Library via FSF, licensed GPL](http://gretl.sourceforge.net/index.html)
is the best source I'm aware of. More links for gretl:
[data for gretl - background, documentation, etc.](http://gretl.sourceforge.net/gretl_data.html)
[Econometric Analysis, 7th Edition - canonical data source](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~wgreene/Text/econometricanalysis.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Whole bunch of UK panel & longitudinal data via UK Data Service - most are not open, but they're pretty easy to register for.

For the major studies see: https://www.ukdataservice.ac.uk/get-data/key-data/cohort-and-longitudinal-studies